# Rails, acts_as_taggable_on: how to get all aricles without tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, find, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on). I have Article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

I know how to find all articles with tag "tag". According to README the solution is: `Article.tagged_with("tag")`.

But how to find all Articles without any tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a classic SQL trick: left join then select lines where second ID is null.

```
Article.
  joins(%Q{LEFT JOIN taggings ON taggings.taggable_id=articles.id AND taggings.taggable_type='Article'}).
  where('taggings.id IS NULL')
```

Comment: @daniel, there's no nice rails way to work with complex joins. Other than that, see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Yes, I agree that `Article.tagged_with(Tag.all.map(&:to_s), :exclude => true)` is more Rails way.
But I'm using Rails 2.3 and want to use this like a named_scope so It is the only way...

Comment: @petRUShka, also, this query is much more efficient.

Comment: That solutions dosn't work in some cases. I faced with following situation: some taggins havn't deleted, but tag_list is empty.

Comment: this is the best way for its performance. dont use ways like `Article.tagged_with(..., :exclude => true)`, it has performance issue becase of many like query.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the source](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/core.rb) for acts-as-taggable-on, you can use the `:exclude` option:

```
##
# Return a scope of objects that are tagged with the specified tags.
#
# @param tags The tags that we want to query for
# @param [Hash] options A hash of options to alter you query:
#                       * <tt>:exclude</tt> - if set to true, return objects that are *NOT* tagged with the specified tags
#                       * <tt>:any</tt> - if set to true, return objects that are tagged with *ANY* of the specified tags
#                       * <tt>:match_all</tt> - if set to true, return objects that are *ONLY* tagged with the specified tags
#                       * <tt>:owned_by</tt> - return objects that are *ONLY* owned by the owner
```

<strike>So in your instance, just do:</strike>

```
Article.tagged_with("tag", :exclude => true)
```

EDIT: Just realized you asked for articles without any tags, in which case, you'll need to supply the list of all your tags to the method:

```
Article.tagged_with(Tag.all.map(&:to_s), :exclude => true)
```

Answer (score 1):

the SQL way looks hackie, and using map is going to be slow for sure.

Here you can get by with two queries (rails 4):

```
ids = Taggings.where(taggable_type: "Article").collect(&:taggable_id).uniq
Article.where.not(id: ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you can do as of rails 5.

```rb
Article.left_joins(:taggings).where(taggings: { tag_id: nil })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the select function. I guess the SQL Solution is much more efficient, but this looks bit more nice:

```
Artical.all.select{|a| a.tags.count == 0 }
```